# ASP.NET MVC error at Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I published an ASP.NET MVC 4 project to Windows Azure, and firstly everything worked fine. But later, sometimes it worked but sometimes I get this error message:

`Server Error in '/' Application.`

`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

`Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

The site does not contains any multimedia or any larger sized data, so I have no idea what cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have not changed any database settings in web.config?

Answer (score 0):

if you publish into VM, it could be possible that one of your instance was in recycling process, it happen because the Load Balancer is round robin.

If you publish on Websites or Cloud Services, we have to look at detail why is it happen.